# Non US-resident, need to file 83b election TODAY with the IRS - I have an SSN but it says "valid for work only with DHS auth" - is this OK?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, irs

I am Canadian and are back in Canada. Last year I had a J1 visa to work in the US and I obtained an SSN while there, it says "valid for work only with DHS authorization" on the SSN. My J1 visa has since expired and I am back in Canada.

While back in Canada I have been working remotely for another US company and have been given stock. I am planning on moving back to the US around the time this stock vests and I was told it was smart to file an 83b election. The 83b election asks for an SSN. I have an SSN. However, it says valid for work only and my J1 visa has since expired.

Am I allowed to still put down my SSN number on the 83b election? I think SSNs are valid for life, but it does say valid for work only and my J1 visa has since expired.

I need to know TODAY because my 30 day 83b window is almost at an end and I need to mail this!

Comment: Is putting the SSN on your 83(b) declaration considered work in the US? What kind of a ridiculous question is this?

Comment: @littleadv I'm not American and it's considered a restricted SSN which I don't know...must mean in some ways it's restricted? Additionally, I've never paid tax anywhere before or dealt with any sort of tax law or the IRS, so if you still think it's ridiculous then good for you.

Comment: SSN is just a number. It cannot be restricted. It's like saying "7 is restricted". That note on your SSN card is only because the SSN *card* is used as a way to identify a person, but the number itself is just a number assigned to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google that "valid for work..." phrase.

You'll find that you have a SSN;  it is valid for many purposes;  it is valid for obtaining work, only when accompanied by DHS authorization.

Doesn't ***anyone*** know how to use commas anymore?